# Error 404 when Tags are clicked

Tags: tagging

I am getting 'Error 404 File Not Found' when I click on tags in Tags Cloud. However, tags are created properly.

What could be the issue? I do not have My Sites also so could that be a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have My Sites Host (you do not need to enable My Sites for all users) properly setup and configured.

Comment: Does My Sites Host require Active Directory (I am on FBA)?

Comment: Nope, it's not necessary