# Error “404 Not Found” when tags (on tag cloud web part) are clicked

Tags: web-part, tagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error 404 when Tags are clicked](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/error-404-when-tags-are-clicked)

How to make link on tag cloud web part works?

I am getting error “404 Not Found” when I click tag link on tag cloud web part,
I have created tag, using tag tool on ribbon , and it showed on tag cloud webpart,  but when i clicked link on tag cloud webpart, the page show error "404 Not Found”.

Suggestion please.....,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need to have My Sites Host properly to work tag links.  properly setup and configure My Sites